# in jdt how to retrieve the absolute path of a jar if it is linked to the project?

Tags: java, jar, eclipse-jdt

i am writing a plugin for eclipse 4.2 that will upload the jars the user adds to a project. 
in order to do this i need to want  to retrieve the location of the jars in the class path.
the problem is that as far as i can see IJavaProject doesn't make the distinction between a linked jar and a copied one.
so when i use IClasspathEntry to retrieve the location of the jar the returned value is a location in the project and not the jars true location.

does any one know how can i retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking for a way to find the file system location of a jar that is inside of a project.

The Eclipse workspace uses an abstraction over the local filesystem that is similar to, but different from the actual filesystem.  There is some API to convert from an `IResource` to a filesystem location.

Typically, the `IClasspathEntry` will return workspace-relative locations when `getPath` is called.  So, to get the filesystem location of a classpath entry, do something like this:

```
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace.getRoot().getFile(entry.getPath()).getLocation();
```